# How to find an element with an ID in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

I have an element with the ID `history` type of `TableView`. How can I find and access this object if I have the instance  of `Scene scene`?

Answer (score 144, accepted):

Try

```
TableView tb = (TableView) scene.lookup("#history");
```

Comment: A pound sign is required when looking up an id. So it should look like this: scene.lookup("#history");

Comment: @Uluk Biy can you update your answer with as TableView tb = (TableView) scene.lookup("#history"); so that others will easily understand by seeing the answer. Thank you.

Comment: There is one important thing. This will work **after** you will invoke ```primaryStage.show()```

Comment: @MAGx2 _This will work after you will invoke primaryStage.show()_ as a general statement, that's not quite right (depends on how the nodes are injected - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68475291/javafx-finding-node-by-id)