# Javafx working with the same window problem

Tags: javafx

What I am trying to do:
I have menu and and after click I am trying to remove unnecessary TextFields.
What I did:
I used this example: 
"In JavaFX, nodes can simply be removed from a Parent (e.g. an AnchorPane) using `.getChildren()` following by `.remove(Object o)`

```
AnchorPane ap;
ap.getChildren().remove(btn);
```

I tried to use:

```
FXMLLoader load=new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("LoginRegister.fxml"));
Parent root = load.load();
root.getChildren();
```

But my root does not have `getChildren()` function.
Where could be the problem?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: FOUND THE ANSWER HERE: [How to access UI components from SceneBuilder in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29463176/how-to-access-ui-components-from-scenebuilder-in-javafx)

WHAT I DID WRONG: I USED IN FXML FILE AND IN CONTROLLER DIFFERENT FX:ID's

Comment: Found the answer, if someone needs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29463176/how-to-access-ui-components-from-scenebuilder-in-javafx

Comment: `Parent` does have a `getChildren()` method but it has `protected` access. You need to use a more specific type that exposes that method publicly, such as `Group` or `Pane`.