# JavaFX, finding node by Id

Tags: java, javafx

I've recently encountered problem, where I needed to get specific node (preferably by id) from nodes used in my window. Im using FXMLLoader, so first idea was to search tree structure FXMLLoader returns.

```
root|  
    |                
    |--some_container |- child1   
    |                 |- child2
    |      
    |--other_container |-child3
    ...
```

Further research got me to method *lookup* in *Scene* class, but official documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html#lookup-java.lang.String-) is a lacking description how this method works and is inaccurate in my opinion (I struggled quite a bit to make things work).

As mentioned here ([How to find an element with an ID in JavaFX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201712/how-to-find-an-element-with-an-id-in-javafx)) invocation of method *lookup* must be **after** method *show*, why?

Second question is why node *id* has to be preceded by '#' (hash sign)? while official documentation states it should be "...CSS selector..."? (Im a bit confused here, because class Node contains only one id-like property)

**Edi1 - simple example for @kleopatra** although problem isn't strictly code, its about understanding.

Example fxml file with scene contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.canvas.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.2" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="display.windows.ConsoleForBoard">
   <children>
      <SplitPane fx:id="mainSplitPane" dividerPositions="0.7" layoutX="277.0" layoutY="100.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <items>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="398.0" prefWidth="404.0">
               <children>
                  <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.8" layoutX="150.0" layoutY="53.0" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="160.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                    <items>
                      <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="160.0">
                           <children>
                              <Canvas fx:id="drawBoard" height="313.0" layoutX="125.0" layoutY="43.0" width="413.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
                           </children>
                        </AnchorPane>
                      <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="160.0">
                           <children>
                              <TextArea layoutX="107.0" layoutY="-86.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
                           </children>
                        </AnchorPane>
                    </items>
                  </SplitPane>
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
               <children>
                  <ToggleButton layoutX="35.0" layoutY="62.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="ToggleButton" />
                  <TextField alignment="CENTER" layoutX="2.0" layoutY="14.0" promptText="Main Menu" text="Main Menu" />
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
        </items>
      </SplitPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**Note:** Canvas has fx:id="drawBoard"

example class that creates this scene:

```
public class BoardWithMenu extends Application {
    Scene mainScene;
    AnchorPane root;
    FXMLLoader loader;

    public static void start() {launch("start");}
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        loader = new FXMLLoader(this.getClass().getResource("scene_definition.fxml"));
        root = loader.load();
        mainScene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);

        stage.setScene(mainScene);
        stage.setTitle("Space map");
        stage.show();

        Canvas board = (Canvas) mainScene.lookup("drawBoard");
        System.out.println(board.getId());
    }
}
```

**Problem:**

Line
`Canvas board = (Canvas) mainScene.lookup("#drawBoard");`
Cannot be invoked before
 `stage.show();`
It will produce null pointer error. Why?

Comment: FXML has the ability to assign an `fx:id` to a node, which can be mapped to a named, typed field in a Controller (using the `@FXML` annotation).  In general, that is a preferred method of referencing a node by ID when FXML is involved.

Comment: Because a CSS selector which selects by ID is given by `#<id>`, where `<id>` is replaced with the actual ID value. That's just how CSS is defined. Keep in mind that the `lookup` method is more "powerful" than just looking up nodes by their ID. As far as I know, any CSS selector you can use in a stylesheet will work with `lookup` (though I've rarely used the method).

Comment: For instance, you can grab the `Text` in a `Button` with `lookup(".button > .text")`. But from quick testing it doesn't look like `lookup` takes pseudo-classes into account.

Comment: Documentation for CSS selectors is [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#id-selectors).

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: If you're using the classes as the API intends them to be used, there would be no need to access the individual UI elements in the `Application.start()` method. The sole purpose of that method is to control application startup. The most you should be doing there is invoking methods on the controller. And, as previously noted, the controller can access the UI elements through the usual `@FXML`-injection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is supplemental to [kleopatra's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68482803/1155209).

**Use Java variable references instead of lookups unless you really need lookups**

My advice is to avoid the CSS-based [lookup](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html) methods if you can (in favor of a direct typed reference in Java).

This advice holds particularly when using FXML.  FXML has the ability to assign an `fx:id` to a node, which can be [mapped to a named, typed field in a Controller](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#controllers) (using the [`@FXML`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#fxml_annotation) annotation). In general, that is a preferred method of referencing a node by ID when FXML is involved.  It is preferred for numerous reasons:

1. When using a Java variable reference rather than a lookup, you have typed information and compile-time checks, rather than untyped runtime checks.
2. Lookups may be time-sensitive: correct results may require a layout pass and/or CSS application.
3. During the layout pass and rendering phases, the JavaFX framework implementation for skins on controls may add or remove various nodes which would change the result of lookups.
4. Using lookups you may find nodes that have been added to the scene by private skin implementations.  By then writing code that relies on those found nodes, you break encapsulation.  A later JavaFX release might change the private skin implementation which changes the structure or nodes which are added by the skin and then breaks your code.

The above points can make it easier to code errors when using lookups rather than relying on Java variable references.

**Understand the difference between an id and an fx:id**

Do not confuse an `fx:id` used in FXML with a [CSS ID](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/ID_selectors), they are different things, though you might often want to assign them to be the same value, you can do that in the definition of the element in FXML, for example:

```
<Button fx:id="myButton" id="myButton">
```

The `fx:id` value will be used to map to a variable reference in a controller which has an `@FXML` annotation (or via reflection on public members if no annotation is provided):

```
@FXML Button myButton;
```

The `id` value will map to the [id](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#getId()) stored in the node and associated with it.  The associated documentation describes it like this:

> The id of this Node. This simple string identifier is useful for finding a specific Node within the scene graph. While the id of a Node should be unique within the scene graph, this uniqueness is not enforced. This is analogous to the "id" attribute on an HTML element (CSS ID Specification).

**Lookups are based on CSS selectors**

Here is an example lookup by ID from the node lookup documentation:

- For example, if a Node is given the id of "myId", then the lookup method can be used to find this node as follows: `scene.lookup("#myId");`.

Lookups can be called on any node, or on the scene.

The node [`lookup(selector)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#lookup(java.lang.String)) methods work based on the node `id`, not the `fx:id` because the lookup string is based on css.  The lookup uses a [css selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors).  So lookup based on an ID will have a `#` prefix in front of the ID because that is the syntax for selecting a node via an ID.  You aren't restricted to only looking up by ID.  The CSS selector syntax is powerful and pretty much a language unto itself so you can have complicated expressions for querying the scene graph node tree and extracting matching nodes if you wish.

**Be aware that skin implementations can modify the scene graph**

If you do want to do a jquery style [find](https://api.jquery.com/find/) (which is kind of what the JavaFX method `lookup` methods are), then be super careful when and how you do it due to kleopatra's second point on nodes inserted by the skin:

> - all nodes that are inserted by the skin are available only after the skin is attached, that is after showing (f.i. "#drawBoard" which is injected to the splitPane's items)

Also, note that skins can be applied in css via the [`fx-skin`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#control) attribute of Controls.  So, even the application of CSS can change the skin, which can change the scene graph which can alter the results of a lookup.

**How to ensure that expected nodes will be found on lookup**

To ensure that all expected nodes are in the scene to be looked up and with the expected attributes applied (e.g. size, color), etc., *before* doing the lookup:

First, add the required nodes to a scene.

Second, do one of the following:

1. [Generate a layout pass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26152642/get-the-height-of-a-node-in-javafx-generate-a-layout-pass) OR
2. [show](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Stage.html#show()) the related stage (which will cause a layout pass) OR
3. Do the lookup in a [`Platform.runLater()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater(java.lang.Runnable)) block.

   - This will wait for the next pulse, so the layout for the current pulse is complete before execution.  Though the `Platform.runLater()` specification doesn't guarantee this, practically, that is how it works.

In most cases, my preferred solution would be to generate the layout pass.

To generate a layout pass:

1. Add all required nodes to a scene with appropriate CSS styles AND
2. Invoke the [`applyCss()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#applyCss()) and [`layout()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Parent.html#layout()) methods on the scene root or an appropriate parent node.

Then invoke your desired lookup methods to find nodes.

**Lookups without explicit layout passes (be careful)**

If you *know* that the elements you want to lookup are already in the scene, then you can directly `lookup()` the nodes and they will be found.  For example, if you just added them to the scene explicitly in a prior piece of code, so you know that they don't need to be created by a Skin on a subsequent pulse.

However, the looked-up nodes may not return the correct initialized values for some attributes such as height or width until after a layout has been performed.  Similarly, any attributes of the looked-up nodes which are set by CSS might be incorrect until CSS has been applied to the nodes.  So for safety's sake me advice would be to err on the side of caution and ensure that layout and CSS are applied to the nodes you want to look up before you try to look them up.

**Summary**

As might be derived from this answer the use of the JavaFX `lookup()` methods come with some warning and caveats.  Which is the reason for the primary recommendation to avoid their use unless they add great benefit to your particular application.

And note, lookups may be of great benefit: they are very powerful, it is quite incredible what some jquery developers achieve using similar functionality, just be careful how you use them.

Comment: _supplemental_ *tss - this is __the__ canonical answer on how/why/when not/use lookup :)) Fully agree that it's expert api - useful when we don't have full control/knowledge about the hierarchy, but the wrong tool when we do have that control/knowledge. Just a comment: weary about suggesting runlater (the outcome is very likely as described, but not guaranteed - technically, it's unrelated to a pulse, afaik)

Comment: Mapping using @FXML annotation is very elegant solution, thank you :)

Comment: "`<Button fx:id="myButton" id="myButton">`" – Just to note, if you _only_ define an `fx:id` then the `FXMLLoader` sets the `id` property to the same value, or at least that's always been the behavior in my previous experience. Though I don't believe that's documented behavior.

Answer (score 4):

The comment you cited:

> As mentioned here ([How to find an element with an ID in JavaFX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201712/how-to-find-an-element-with-an-id-in-javafx))
> invocation of method lookup must be after method show?

is wrong as a general statement. Whether or not a node can be looked-up immediately after loading depends on how it is added:

- all nodes that are injected as children are available directly after loader (f.i. "#mainSplitPane" as child of root)
- all nodes that are inserted by the skin are available only after the skin is attached, that is after showing (f.i. "#drawBoard" which is injected to the splitPane's items)